# Count all values found within a grouped dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping

Suppose I have some demographic data as such

```
demographic.data <- data.frame(nation=c('us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'us', 'china', 'china', 'china'),
                               religion=c('christ', 'budhist', 'christ', 'jew', 'jew', 'christ', 'budhist', 'budhist'))

#  nation religion
#1     us   christ
#2     us  budhist
#3     us   christ
#4     us      jew
#5     us      jew
#6  china   christ
#7  china  budhist
#8  china  budhist
```

I want to calculate the a mass function for religions within each nation. So I **could** do something like `group_by()` the nation and then aggregate by a bunch of `sum()`s.

```
religion.distributions <- demographic.data %>%
  group_by(nation) %>%
  summarise(n       = n(),
            christ  = sum(religion == 'christ'),
            jew     = sum(religion == 'jew'),
            budhist = sum(religion == 'budhist'))

#  nation     n christ   jew budhist
#
#1 china      3      1     0       2
#2 us         5      2     2       1
```

Although this produces the correct result for this data, the problem is that I am required to hard-code the religions I want to sum up. This will be a problem if any new religions appear in the data.

Is there a way to *automatically* have columns for the count of every religion within each group? It should be able to look at all the possible values in the `religion` column and start counting them. Solutions that use a `dplyr` pipeline would be most elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `spread` with `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
demographic.data %>% 
    group_by(nation) %>% 
    mutate(n = n()) %>% 
    count(nation, religion, n) %>% 
    spread(religion, nn, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   nation [2]
#  nation     n budhist christ   jew
#  <fct>  <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#1 china      3       2      1     0
#2 us         5       1      2     2
```